# I have a marker on google maps, which on click should show a text content

Tags: javascript, onclick, google-maps-markers, show-hide, infowindow

The marker on click will call a function called calcRoute. I also want to display a text content near the marker when the marker is clicked.

```
var textContent = "Some text";

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: MALL.mall.name,
            position: pos
        });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function () {
            calcRoute();
        }));
```

Comment: And what is currently happening?

Comment: They're called info windows: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

Comment: @Diodeus now the above code is working fine and it calls the function calcRoute(), just that I want to add the feature of displaying the textContent on click which I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that you've tagged your question "infowindow", you should try it:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: textContent
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function () {
    calcRoute();
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}));
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows